# Creating class names from source map keys

Tags: sass

I'm getting an error saying that ('background-color': #333) is not valid css. I'm trying to get the theme name to append to .body-- for each theme (there's only one them for now). The error looks to me like it's trying to add the contents of theme-name to .body-- instead of just the title of it.

```
$themes: (
    'dark': (
        'background-color': #333
    ),
);

@each $theme-name in $themes {
    .body--#{$theme-name} {
        & .container {
            background-color: map-get($theme-name, background-color);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get:

```
.body--dark {}
.body--dark .container {background-color: #333}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `@each` statement. You are getting just the map value, instead of the key **and** the value.

```
$themes: (
    'dark': (
        'background-color': #333
    ),
);

// get the key and the value in two separate variables: first variable is the key, second one the value
@each $theme-name, $theme-config in $themes {
    .body--#{$theme-name} {
        .container {
            background-color: map-get($theme-config, 'background-color');
        }
    }
}
```

As a note, you don’t need the `&` for nested selectors. That’s just the default behavior. Use the `&` only for pseudo classes, concatenate class names, aggregated class names and some other strange selector usages. Check my answer about this note on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50661041/9503418).